# Using ClientBundle image resources in css urls

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder

I'm building an application in GWT and have a skin from my graphic designer which I've plugged into the app using UIBinder and it works beautifully. Now I want to bundle all the images using ClientBundle.

Mayne of these images are used in the css file e.g.

.nav{background:url(nav_bg.jpg) left top repeat-x; height:27px; clear:both;}

Before this css I have defined a  tag to include the bundle.

How can I change the css entry so that it uses an ImageResource from my ClientBundle? I guess I can do inline styles for all the html tags but that's horrible separation and a lot of extra work.

I have successfully used ImageResources in the html part of the uibinder file (e.g. in a ) but I cannot see how to do this in the css. I have even inlined the css in a  block but I still don't see the correct way to do this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

ClientBundles can now be used to host CssResources as well.
These CssResources are CSS files with some extra functionality.

The docs of GWT describes what you need in the section about [ImageSprites](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#Image_Sprites).

Comment: True but at the price of sacrificing IE6 support.

Also I can't see how to specify the "left top" part of the css rule. Only the repeat-x property seems to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up skipping GWT css and image bundling altogether. Instead I've had my carve done using a css sprited image block made by the design/carve team. This has these advantages.

1/ Much less css porting since I can plug the html directly into ui binder and use the css tags from the carve i.e. not using uibinder css. As long as the html structure matches the carve then this is a lot less work than migrating all the css into gwt css.

2/ It also allows me to use svn/diff when applying changes - this was not possible when using gwt css/image spriting.

3/ I can easily put the image/css files on a CDN since the load tags are in the host page and don't suffer from Same Origin restrictions. FYI : yes I know about the XS linker as another way to do this.

It stops being useful when the carve uses css for positioning and I want to use LayoutPanels but that's not too bad as long as I request that the layout css is separate from the style css.

So in the end I discovered that, when working with design/carve from a third party, it's much easier to avoid using gwt css/images but to reproduce the same benefits using traditional css spriting and minification. I hope this helps someone.